# Undefined variable '$result'.intelephense(1008)

Tags: php, function, variables, error-handling, var

i follow a video to create a login page on my website in php and everything is cool until one of my php files don't make the job because $result is not define , here is the error : Undefined variable '$result'.intelephense(1008)

i tried var $result, $result = 0 , $result = true or $result = false but nothing is working , i give you some code , and if you can help me it's fantastic ! :)

```
<?php

function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) {
    $result;
    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdrepeat) ) {
        $result = true ;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidUid($username) {
    $result;
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        $result = true ;
    } 
    else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) {
    $result;
```

<-- in the moment $result is undefined, error is expected (in "invalidUid()" below too).

What is this line
`$result;`
for? It's useless, isn't it?

Comment: the guy in the video write this to declare the var in the function so ze can use is multiple time :/

Comment: OK, but:

1. `$result = '';` or `$result = FALSE;` etc. is declaration of variable, but

2. `$result;` (*) or `echo $result;` or `print_r($result);` etc. is a use of variable, not declaration;

* = this one very ofter may be incorrect use, moreover.

Comment: ok , so if i undertstand , i ask for the result of `$result` instead of declare it , so my code doesn't  work. how can i declare it to make my code work?  :)

Comment: Remove both lines ```$result;``` and try...

Comment: BTW,  consider code below (differences in preg_match etc.)

`var_dump(invalidUid('johny'));

var_dump(invalidUid('')); /* FALSE - not OK */

function invalidUid_($username) {
    $result = true;
    if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $username)) {
        $result = false ;
    } 
    return $result;
}

var_dump(invalidUid_('')); /* TRUE - OK */
`
<https://3v4l.org/gV0gn#v7.4.27>